# Load content from external page into another page using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to do this?

page1.php
--has

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="content">hello</div>
</div>
```

index.php
--has

```
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Can I somehow grab the data from page1.php inside of the `content` div and load it into the `main` div in my index.php?

I have done this with the code provided at css-tricks url: http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicPage/

But this uses hash change events. I don't want to use the hash feature, just the load content feature, but I can't seem to isolate the code for that because I think it's built into the bbq hashchange plugin.

Is there an Ajax way of doing it?

Something like

```
$(selector).find('#main').load('#content');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put a filtering selector after the URL in [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s first argument:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load('page1.php #content');
});
```

That will inject the #main div in the current page with the contents of #content from page1.php.

Comment: After 4 hours! god bless you for this answer!