# Load first div from another page using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery

I am not ever sure this is possible but I know you guys will know the answer.

I wonder if it is possible to load the first div on a page into a different page.

Example:

This code is on "list.php"

```
<div class="message_details">
Some Content 1
</div>
<div class="message_details">
Some Content 2
</div>
```

I found this article and it works but it brings in all div's but I want to load only the first div.

[Load content from external page into another page using Ajax/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560183/load-content-from-external-page-into-another-page-using-ajax-jquery)

Here is the code I have now that loads all divs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").load('list.php .message_details');
});
```

How can I load only the first div? Also is there any way to remove an img tag within the selected div?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` selector

```
$(".loader").load('list.php .message_details:first-child', function() {
    $(this).find("img").remove();
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Comment: I knew it would be something easy like that. Do you know if there is a way to strip out any img tags?

Comment: Actually this should be done in the callback, ill write it up in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply echo the the div in the second page. Give each div an id, then echo that. (unless i am misunderstanding your goal)