# Loading contents from another page into a variable as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the HTML of a div from another page in a variable as a string, so I can run a regex search to find a specific number?

Comment: It sure is, but on the clientside only, it probably isn't ?

Comment: from same domain yes, from other domain you'll need to proxify it server side

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560183/load-content-from-external-page-into-another-page-using-ajax-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that *other page* **is in your own domain:**
 *[**jsBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/miroxe/2/edit?html,js,console,output)*

```
$('<div />').load("otherpage.html", function(data){
  var num = /\d+/.exec( $(this).find("#number").text() );
  console.log( num ); // 45
});
```

<sup>**Note**: the above presumes the desired number is somewhere inside the `#number` element. The regex `/\d+/` is used to get all the numbers from that element.</sup>

---

If the page is **not in your domain:**
***[jQuery load external site page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999573/jquery-load-external-site-page)***

you'll first need to get that page content using PHP with `file_get_contents`. After the desired content is on your server you'll not run any more into security issues and you can than respond to AJAX with the grabbed content.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading content from the same domain, the answer @lawrence overflow linked to in his comment will do the trick:[Load content from external page into another page using Ajax/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560183/load-content-from-external-page-into-another-page-using-ajax-jquery?rq=1)

JS with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load('sourcePage.html #content');
});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use server-side technology. Here's a Node.js server that proxies for another site:

JS (Node and Express):

```
var request=require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Put the source URL here:
var URL='http://www.nytimes.com';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.type('.html');
    request(URL,function(err,response,body){
        res.send(body);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: instead of wrapping around the head how to install Node and stuff, one line of PHP and AJAX (standard jQuery snip) is quite enough.

Comment: I wanted to show how to clip the page to a certain region and also how to make the solution more flexible. Plus, this was tagged as a JavaScript question, so I gave a JavaScript answer. Could you give your PHP solution?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan: I simplified the code in response to your comments. Fair enough.

Comment: Mheiber, Here's my PHP solution, which basically differs by just one line of PHP. The AJAX is basically the same. The solution can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999573/jquery-load-external-site-page (upvoted your answer for the shown effort!)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the elegant PHP solution and upvote. I'm sure there's a simpler Node solution, but I'm too used to Express.